# Java - How to acces to a var with a dynamic name?

Tags: java, mysql, eval

I access my database that has several fields:

- `rabbit2013`
- `rabbit2014`
- `rabbit2015`
- etc.

I am trying to create a program in Java to read the variable of the current year (`rabbit2015` here). I have the current year in my variable `year`. How do I return the value of `"rabbit"+year`?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js"); 
Object result = null;
try {
    result = engine.eval("rabbit"+year);
}
catch (ScriptException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Have you got any ideas?

EDIT:

```
Error : ReferenceError: "rabbit2015" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: sry, look at edit plz :)

Comment: @Antoine How have you connected the database to `engine`?

Comment: Do you want me to give you all my code ? (178 lines).

Comment: @Antoine No. But from the error it looks like the engine doesn't have a variable called `rabbit2015`. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be preferable.

Comment: If I don't make a mistake, I gave you the code in the introduction. Imagine I have a variable "rabbit205" create a little bit earlier that contains "hello";

Comment: @Antoine If you're talking about the screenshot posted as a comment to the answer below, then you're obviously not binding anything to the engine that it could interpret as `rabbit2015`. You're saying that there are fields in a database, but how do those fields get to the engine? And why are you doing this with a JavaScript engine in the first place? Can't you get data from the database to Java directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = engine.eval("\"rabbit\"+year");
```

The way you had it, Java was evaluating "rabbit"+year, then passing that to the eval method.

Assuming "year" is a java variable, you'll also need to put it on the ScriptEngine binding...

```
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("year", year);
```

Then you pass the bindings in as a second parameter when you call eval()...

```
    result = engine.eval("\"rabbit\"+year", bindings);
```

Comment: I realised... Check revised answer

Comment: Thanks, now it's say me that : ReferenceError: "year" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1

Comment: Yes, that's because there's no "year" variable in your JavaScript. You need to pass it into the JavaScript space by putting it on the ScriptEngine binding. I'll dig out some for you code shortly

Comment: Thanks, and you put theses lines after "ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");" ?

Comment: Yes. After you get the engine, and before you evaluate.

Comment: Did you remember to add the bindings to your call to eval?

Comment: See my comment of 1 minute ago, and the edit I made to the answer. You need to pass the bindings into the eval method.

Comment: Thanks, but now its print me "rabbit2015" xD How can i have the value of this var ? ^^

Comment: Your script concatenates  "rabbit" and the value of year, which is 2015. That's exactly what it's done. It's working perfectly now. What else would you expect it to do!?!!

Comment: I've got a var (at the top of the page) whose name is "rabbit2015". Like that : String rabbit2015 = "lol"; how can i print "lol" :P (Remeber the year will change, don't ansferme "System.out.println(rabbit2015);" ^^

Comment: At the top of what page? Do you mean a web page? If so, then I think you may have misunderstood what the ScriptingEngine does unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78922/discussion-between-antoine-and-phil-anderson).

Comment: Last comment I'm making on this as it's getting way too long. If you mean that rabbit2015 is a Java String variable, then that's what you should put in the binding like so - bindings.put("java2015", java2015); Then you'd evaluate like you originally did, but with the binding passed in like so - result = eval("rabbit" + year, bindings); I hope this works for you, but I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to achieve so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer of my question :
PS : When i talk you about rabits, it were examples, here it's "aRealiserEn"+year
I think I was not well enough explained my problem (promiss i will do better next). I thank all the same people who took time to read me and answer me (especially [Phil Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380618/phil-anderson) and [Biffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen)).
[image: solutions's code]